# How does PDF to Postscript conversion work?

Tags: pdf, postscript

I understand the basic process of PS to PDF conversion. The PS is a program that draws, so the PS interpreter runs the program and draws the object, then renders those objects into the PDF envelope.

How does this process work in reverse? Is the basic idea to treat each object element in the PDF file as an image and then create a set of PS instructions that draws each image?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that PS->PDF conversion works by **rendering** the PostScript drawing operations, that would imply a bitmap. In general the marking operations are cpatured, and then equivalent marking operations are written using PDF constructs.

Now PDF is a description language, not a programming language. This means that when starting from PDF we have the object description immediely available instead of running a program to generate it. So its a much easier to task to take each description and turn it into a PostScript program.

In fact, many such conversions actually work by defining the PDF operators as PostScript routines, and then just dump the PDF operations directly. For example:

```
  /m /moveto load def
  /l /lineto load def
  /c /curveto load def
  /v { currentpoint 6 2 roll curveto } bind def
  /y { 2 copy curveto } bind def
  /re {
    4 2 roll moveto  exch dup 0 rlineto  0 3 -1 roll rlineto  neg 0 rlineto
    closepath
  } def
```

The real problem comes when dealing with PDF features which can't be represented in PostScript, in the main this means transparency. Because there is no way to create PostScript vector descriptions to match the PDF descriptions (difference in the graphics models) in this case the transparent areas, at least, must be rendered to a bitmap image, and the image inserted into the PostScript program.